# recognition speech is not recognising user utterances properly in android with dialogflow integration

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk, integration, dialogflow-es

I am facing an issue while implementing dialogflow integration with android custom app. Sometimes recognition engine identifies user utterances properly and most of the time it's doesn't. So how can we improve the recognition engine so it can understand user utterances more accurately. 
I have used android dialogflow sdk for integration with the following git repository :-

[git link](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client)

But this link doesn't solve my issue.

One more solution i found is that we can use google's prompt using android Intent which has better recognition engine.
here is the code for android Intent which generates a pop-up like this and it recognise user utterance more appropriate:-

[image]

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say hi or hello");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10);
startActivity(intent);
```

But the issue is how can we integrate android intent with AI Services to use dialogflow so that we can configure AI Services like **Language support, Recognition engine type and access token of dialogflow**

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Can anyone help me on the issue please?